# How to Filter Django Queryset

Tags: django, filter, django-queryset

How do I filter in a queryset after the initial query? Essentially I am trying to remove an Item from a queryset (without deleting it from the database).

```
accounts = company_account.objects.filter(company=userinfo.company).all()
    for account in accounts:
        if not search in account.first_name_lower+" "+account.last_name_lower:
            account.remove()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can apply Manager's methods to a QuerySet objects.

First:

The `.all()` at the end is not needed in:

```
accounts = company_account.objects.filter(company=userinfo.company).all()
# this is the same that
accounts = company_account.objects.filter(company=userinfo.company)
```

Second:

If you want to exclude an object from the queryset, you can use:

```
accounts = accounts.exclude(**criteria**)
```

Third:

For your case, you could try this with [Concat](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/database-functions/#concat) (Django 1.8+):

```
from django.db.models import Value, CharField
from django.db.models.functions import Concat

accounts.annotate(full_name=Concat('first_name_lower', Value(' '), 'last_name_lower'),
                  output_field=CharField()).exclude(full_name=something_here)
```

Comment: The problem with exclude is that I need to exclude based off of two values: first_name_lower and last_name lower so I need to remove queryset items outside of the typical exclude.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use queryset API in this way. In your case, you just need use `Q` object to filter your `company_account`:

```
accounts = company_account.objects.filter(
     Q(first_name_lower__icontain=search) |
     Q(last_name_lower__icontain=search),
     company=userinfo.company,
).distinct()
```

Or better, use full text search approach. Or use raw SQL query.